# React children functional props not working

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, the following error reported in console:

`Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

What is wrong?

```
function Test({children}) {
  return (
    <div>
     {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test> {() => (<h1>Title</h1>)}</Test>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the render props pattern is that the child component calls the children as a function in order to render it.

If you expect to have either normal `ReactNode`s or a function, you'll need to check to see if the children is a function to determine how to use it.

If you expect children will always be a function you can just call it without the type check first, though there will be an error if you pass in something that isn't callable.

```js
function Test({children}) {
  return (
    <div>
     {typeof children==='function'? children() : children}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test>{() => (<h1>Title</h1>)}</Test>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

In addition, you need to make sure there's no extra whitespace before the curly braces to set up the render props function, otherwise it is interpreted as ['', function(){}] which won't work:

```
      <Test> {() => (<h1>Title</h1>)}</Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test><h1>Title</h1></Test> // Change hehre
    </div>
  );
}
```